# tf optimizer compute_gradients error Dimension size

Tags: tensorflow, reshape

I am trying to utilize [`DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer`](https://tensorflow.google.cn/responsible_ai/privacy/api_docs/python/tf_privacy/v1/DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer#class-variables) to calculate compute_gradients.

By followed the [documents](https://tensorflow.google.cn/responsible_ai/privacy/api_docs/python/tf_privacy/v1/DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer#class-variables), `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is used then applied to `tf.reduce_mean()` to calculate the loss.

```
    crx_entropy_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                        labels=context[:, 1:], logits=output['logits'][:, :-1])
    print('crx_entropy_loss', crx_entropy_loss.shape, crx_entropy_loss)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(crx_entropy_loss)
    print('reduce_mean_loss', loss.shape, loss)
```

which,

```
crx_entropy_loss -> 
shape: (1, ?) from Tensor("SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Reshape_2:0", shape=(1, ?), dtype=float32)

reduce_mean_loss -> 
shape: () from Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

But, when I tried to calculate optimizer gradients `compute_gradients`, it shows dimension error.

```
opt = dp_optimizer.DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer(
            l2_norm_clip=l2_norm_clip,
            noise_multiplier=noise_multiplier,
            num_microbatches= batch_size, 
            unroll_microbatches=True,
            ledger=ledger,
            learning_rate=learning_rate )

opt_grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss, train_vars)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1607, in _create_c_op
c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl
.
InvalidArgumentError
:
Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 128 but is 1 for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [128,?].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GenerateTextMy.py", line 80, in <module>
main()
  File "GenerateTextMy.py", line 50, in main
gpt2.finetune(sess, folder, batch_size = 128, multi_gpu = True, sample_every = 10000,
  File "/home/gpt_2_simple_dp/gpt_2.py", line 253, in finetune
opt_grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss, train_vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_privacy/privacy/optimizers/dp_optimizer.py", line 134, in compute_gradients
microbatches_losses = tf.reshape(loss, [self._num_microbatches, -1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 131, in reshape
result = gen_array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 8114, in reshape
_, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 792, in _apply_op_helper
op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None, name=scope,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 513, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3356, in create_op
return self._create_op_internal(op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3418, in _create_op_internal
ret = Operation(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1769, in __init__
self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1610, in _create_c_op
raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError
:
Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 128 but is 1 for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [128,?].
```

I did google and looked through StackOverflow with related topics, however, I still don't quite get the issue. My code is only able to execute when the batch size is 1.
May I ask for some advice or some help?

In addition, why my loss is in shape 0 or None, then it will show the error?

Version:
Tensorflow-1.15
Python 3.8.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Tensorflow documentation on DPGradientDescentGaussianOptimizer, it is written:

```
# Compute loss as a tensor. Do not call tf.reduce_mean as you
# would with a standard optimizer.
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=labels, logits=logits)

train_op = opt.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

The problem is that you were using tf.reduce_mean